# Rewrite slug for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I have made and registered a CPT called 'generic'. When I set a CPT page in the menu, the address is

```
www.sitename.com/generic/pagename
```

I want to make the slug for this CPT simply be

```
www.sitename.com/pagename
```

I have tried `'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),` when registering the post, but this has no effect. I have also tried `'rewrite' => array('slug' => get_site_url()),`

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to link your CPT archive in a menu:

```
        'has_archive'  => true,
        'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'generic', 'with_front' => false ),
```

After you re-save your permalinks, you can then add the link to your menu like this example:

```
www.example.com/generic
```